# What security risk does it mean if you have your db password and security token publicity available?

Tags: databases, wordpress

In Germany everyone is worried about a prominent political party that exposes their `wp-config` to the public:

https://www.a***********r.de/wp-config.php

How much of a security risk is that? The db, for example, is only reachable from a local ip.

What information can an attacker actually use and how high is the risk?

Content of the file:

```
define('DB_NAME',   'afd-web-wp-dev');
define('DB_USER',   'afd-web-dev');
define('DB_PASSWORD',   'm*******d'); //redacted for privacy
define('DB_HOST',   '10.*.*.*'); //redacted for privacy

define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

$table_prefix  = 'e******y_'; //redacted for privacy

define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: additional: they show everything from Wordpress. Even things like a ca-bundle.crt

Answer (score 3):

It is an information disclosure that weakens the overall security of the website. By itself, I would rate this vulnerability as medium risk but an overall analysis is required in order to determine how this affects the overall security.

The database password could be reused in a different location, it can hint on how other passwords are built and what character sets are used. Maybe the database is accessible in case the website shares hosting with other websites. The `table_prefix` parameter can prevent exploitation in case there is a vulnerability in the website that allows SQL injection. With the information in `table_prefix` public, such protection is no longer provided.

It is also visible that the WordPress security keys are not initialized. WordPress Security Keys are a set of random variables that improve encryption strength of information stored in the user’s cookies. These security keys makes it harder for an attacker to crack a WordPress password.

Answer (score 2):

*The db, for example, is only reachable from a local ip.*

If the Wordpress is on a shared host, it's just a matter of subscribing to the same provider to "have fun", because the "local IP" will suddenly be accessible.